# How to integrate Inmobi Ads in Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, inmobi

```
<Ad:IMAdView
   x:Name="AdView1"
   RefreshInterval="30"
   AdSize="15"
   AppId="My App Id Here"
   Height="50" Width="320"
   AnimationType="SLIDE_IN_LEFT" Margin="67,242,69,315">

                <Ad:IMAdView.IMAdRequest>
                    <Ad:IMAdRequest 
         LocationInquiryAllowed="False">
                    </Ad:IMAdRequest>
                </Ad:IMAdView.IMAdRequest>
            </Ad:IMAdView>
```

I'm new in Windows Phone Development. I would like to know how to add inmobi Ads to my application. I have registered on Inmobi and also have my Property Id. I used the given code in XAML to dislay the Ads, but it doesn't work.

Here are Some Logs.

> 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: DefaultDomain):
>   Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols.
>   Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight
>   AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll'. Skipped
>   loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My
>   Code' is enabled. 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll:
>   Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols.
>   Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight
>   AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.ni.dll'. Skipped
>   loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My
>   Code' is enabled. 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll:
>   Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.ni.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR
>   C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols.
>   Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight
>   AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\Data\Programs{FCC4C048-4686-42BC-A40C-B7FE8DA70B40}\Install\Match1.DLL'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll:
>   Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols.
>   Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight
>   AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll'. Skipped loading
>   symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is
>   enabled. 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll:
>   Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\Data\Programs{FCC4C048-4686-42BC-A40C-B7FE8DA70B40}\Install\InMobiWPAdSDK.DLL'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR
>   C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.ni.dll'. Skipped loading
>   symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is
>   enabled. 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll:
>   Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.Linq.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols.
>   Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight
>   AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Core.ni.dll'. Skipped
>   loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My
>   Code' is enabled. 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll:
>   Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\System.Device.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols.
>   Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight
>   AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll'. Skipped
>   loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My
>   Code' is enabled. 2014-07-06 00:53:26,243 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG
>   UserAgent: [Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0;
>   Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; Microsoft; Virtual)]
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight
>   AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR
>   C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\en-US\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll'. Module was
>   built without symbols. An exception of type
>   'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in InMobiWPAdSDK.DLL and
>   wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary 2014-07-06
>   00:53:28,150 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 ERROR An error occured at
>   Helper.GetCurrentPage:: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object. Publisher device Id is: 19kJy545FwEVqg22z7oQugRpmuc=
>   2014-07-06 00:53:28,290 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG Sending Ad Request
>   [u-id-map=NcG%2F%2Fo3zeGVybiTZv0QNrAD7YRFoH244AL%2FkKIDRswMHgPuTiGXT90z7Hij3ZNX6H5xo6IOEuaGpf2WdVZBiaBRzouDvax1KG4rb0pB3VX3pY20Wly0PPKPcacF3T4yDKUL5QiMbDEs%2FLis12kfvwdu4LKUWYEfeYR1pk5z%2BshM%3D&u-id-key=1680336346&u-key-ver=1&aid=19kJy545FwEVqg22z7oQugRpmufx44b5xXnbw889oDs%3D&d-device-screen-size=480*800&d-localization=en-US&d-orientation=1&d-devicename=XDeviceEmulator&u-appver=1.0.0.0&u-appdnm=Match1&u-appbid=fcc4c048-4686-42bc-a40c-b7fe8da70b40&mk-siteid=26e654aa92d146fbac8f1640acf31030&mk-version=pr-SWPH-CTATE-20140116&mk-rel-version=pr-SWPH-CTATE-20140116&format=xhtml&mk-ads=1&h-user-agent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(compatible%3B%20MSIE%2010.0%3B%20Windows%20Phone%208.0%3B%20Trident%2F6.0%3B%20IEMobile%2F10.0%3B%20ARM%3B%20Touch%3B%20Microsoft%3B%20Virtual)&mk-ad-slot=11&u-rt=1]
>   2014-07-06 00:53:28,359 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG
>   ServerURL:http://i.w.inmobi.com:80/showad.asm 2014-07-06 00:53:28,365
>   InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG   NetworkManager.GetAd--> Request Message:
>   u-id-map=NcG%2F%2Fo3zeGVybiTZv0QNrAD7YRFoH244AL%2FkKIDRswMHgPuTiGXT90z7Hij3ZNX6H5xo6IOEuaGpf2WdVZBiaBRzouDvax1KG4rb0pB3VX3pY20Wly0PPKPcacF3T4yDKUL5QiMbDEs%2FLis12kfvwdu4LKUWYEfeYR1pk5z%2BshM%3D&u-id-key=1680336346&u-key-ver=1&aid=19kJy545FwEVqg22z7oQugRpmufx44b5xXnbw889oDs%3D&d-device-screen-size=480*800&d-localization=en-US&d-orientation=1&d-devicename=XDeviceEmulator&u-appver=1.0.0.0&u-appdnm=Match1&u-appbid=fcc4c048-4686-42bc-a40c-b7fe8da70b40&mk-siteid=26e654aa92d146fbac8f1640acf31030&mk-version=pr-SWPH-CTATE-20140116&mk-rel-version=pr-SWPH-CTATE-20140116&format=xhtml&mk-ads=1&h-user-agent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(compatible%3B%20MSIE%2010.0%3B%20Windows%20Phone%208.0%3B%20Trident%2F6.0%3B%20IEMobile%2F10.0%3B%20ARM%3B%20Touch%3B%20Microsoft%3B%20Virtual)&mk-ad-slot=11&u-rt=1
>   2014-07-06 00:53:28,374 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG Sent Ad Request A first
>   chance exception of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll Loaded Container: *************** Loaded Container:
>   *************** Loaded Container: *************** Loaded Container: *************** 2014-07-06 00:53:29,247 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG AdResponse [<,bp,bp,h.bodyk,S.f(b))};f[a+A]=function(a){T(c,a)};f[a+K]=function(){U(c)};f[a+N]=function(a,b){V(c,a,b)}}f.inmobi.Bolt=S;
>   S.f=function(a){if(typeof a.click==E)a.click.call(a);else
>   if(a.fireEvent)a.fireEvent(L);else if(a.dispatchEvent){var
>   c=h.createEvent(w);c.initEvent(z,!1,!0);a.dispatchEvent(c)}};S.b=function(a){return
>   a.replace(/\$TS/g,q+(new Date).getTime())};function W(a,c){var
>   d=h.getElementById(a.a+B),b=hn;bp;bp;bp;bp;dk}
>   function T(a,c){var d=f[a.a+H];d&&d();for(var
>   d=a.c.length,b=0;bn;bp;bp;bp;ck;var
>   g=b.contentWindow;g&&g.document.write(d)}catch(m){}} function
>   V(a,c,d){function b(c,d,g){if(!(0>=g)){var
>   m=h.getElementById(a.a+B),l=hn;lp;lp;lp;void
>   0!=l.addEventListener&&l.addEventListener(C,function(){f.setTimeout(function(){3E5k}}var
>   g=a.e,g=g+(v+c);if(d)for(var m in
>   d)g+=r+e(m)+u+e(d[m]);b(g,1E3,5);18==c&&U(a);8==c&&T(a,null)};})();
>   new
>   window.inmobi.Bolt({"lp":"http://diagnostics-lp.inmobi.com","lps":"https://prclick.inmobi.com/redir/http://diagnostics-lp.inmobi.com","ct":["http://c.w.inmobi.com/c.asm/C/t/dtuccbshdf/10nu/c/b/a0/u/0/0/0/eyJVSUQiOiIxOWtKeTU0NUZ3RVZxZzIyejdvUXVnUnBtdWNcdTAwM2QiLCJPMSI6IjE5a0p5NTQ1RndFVnFnMjJ6N29RdWdScG11Y1x1MDAzZCIsIklYIjoiZGM3NjUyN2NiN2E0YTlkMTU0NDJiZjcxMjc4MTE5NTYifQ~~/0fbe0b07-0147-1000-f1b8-408b1fe90067/w204/0/-1/1/1/x/2608772/NW/2t/0/sdk/2.0.4/dir/ZmNjNGMwNDgtNDY4Ni00MmJjLWE0MGMtYjdmZThkYTcwYjQw/6/23016cb8?at\u003d1\u0026am\u003d0"],"bcu":"http://et.w.inmobi.com/c.asm/C/t/dtuccbshdf/10nu/c/b/a0/u/0/0/0/eyJVSUQiOiIxOWtKeTU0NUZ3RVZxZzIyejdvUXVnUnBtdWNcdTAwM2QiLCJPMSI6IjE5a0p5NTQ1RndFVnFnMjJ6N29RdWdScG11Y1x1MDAzZCIsIklYIjoiZGM3NjUyN2NiN2E0YTlkMTU0NDJiZjcxMjc4MTE5NTYifQ~~/0fbe0b07-0147-1000-f1b8-408b1fe90067/w204/0/-1/0/1/x/2608772/NW/2t/0/sdk/2.0.4/dir/ZmNjNGMwNDgtNDY4Ni00MmJjLWE0MGMtYjdmZThkYTcwYjQw/6/483996cb","ws":true,"ns":"im_5954_"});
>   (function() {var
>   b=window,c='handleClick',d='handleTouchEnd',f='handleTouchStart';b.inmobi=b.inmobi||{};var
>   g=b.inmobi;function h(a,e){return function(l){e.call(a,l)}}function
>   k(a,e){this.b=e;this.a=this.c=!1;b[a+c]=h(this,this.click);b[a+f]=h(this,this.start);b[a+d]=h(this,this.end)}k.prototype.click=function(){this.c||this.b()};k.prototype.start=function(a){this.a=this.c=!0;a&&a.preventDefault()};k.prototype.end=function(){this.a&&(this.a=!1,this.b())};g.OldTap=k;})();
>   new window.inmobi.OldTap("im_5954_", function() {
>   window'im_5954_openLandingPage';
>   window'im_5954_clickCallback'; }); </script>   </div> body{margin:0}</style>
>    im_5954_recordEvent(18);
>   </script>]]></Ad></Ads></AdResponse> ] 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR
>   C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\System.ServiceModel.Web.ni.dll'. Skipped loading
>   symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is
>   enabled. 2014-07-06 00:53:30,178 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG
>   Current_SizeChanged Screen Size: [{"height":800,"width":480}] Mraid
>   Rotation Angle:[0]  2014-07-06 00:53:30,196 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG
>   Raising screen position change event 2014-07-06 00:53:30,225 InMobi
>   SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG Screen position
>   {"height":90,"width":728,"x":-2,"y":702} 2014-07-06 00:53:30,225
>   InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG Ad container recieved script
>   notificationlog|Bridge::fireOrientationChangeEvent. Orientation:0
>   2014-07-06 00:53:30,241 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG
>   Bridge::fireOrientationChangeEvent. Orientation:0 2014-07-06
>   00:53:30,256 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG Ad container recieved script
>   notificationlog|Bridge:: fireStateChangeEvent Called. State:default
>   2014-07-06 00:53:30,272 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG Bridge::
>   fireStateChangeEvent Called. State:default 2014-07-06 00:53:30,272
>   InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG Ad container recieved script
>   notificationlog|Bridge:: fireViewableChangeEvent called.
>   IsViewable:true 2014-07-06 00:53:30,288 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG
>   Bridge:: fireViewableChangeEvent called. IsViewable:true 2014-07-06
>   00:53:30,288 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG Ad container recieved script
>   notificationlog|Bridge::firePlacementChangeEvent called.
>   Placement:inline 2014-07-06 00:53:30,303 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG
>   Bridge::firePlacementChangeEvent called. Placement:inline 2014-07-06
>   00:53:30,319 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG Ad container recieved script
>   notificationlog|Bridge:: fireReadyEvent called 2014-07-06 00:53:30,319
>   InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG Bridge:: fireReadyEvent called 2014-07-06
>   00:53:30,338 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG IMAdView::IMAdContainer_AdRendered
>   SecondIMAdContainer Ad request loaded. The thread 0x910 has exited
>   with code 259 (0x103). 2014-07-06 00:53:51,031 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG
>   UserAgent: [Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0;
>   Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; Microsoft; Virtual)] Publisher
>   device Id is: 19kJy545FwEVqg22z7oQugRpmuc= 2014-07-06 00:53:51,163
>   InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG Sending Ad Request
>   [u-id-map=TLqn3wQW8B%2BDNjTXtCX3SXsOxxaoFICPINnBAvgwJMlDM12JpBKkXE%2FmTDdFaEFYDvq0p0sfhm8VkXXBKF7JYGdUg5Os7sHAIy%2BzTbE0DAC4oBtTLoEGaGNaCUbvrExJRBMtYY5T9Nmg6%2BUwT9I2PieNvMOfuQoj4wNGQZ%2FLSBc%3D&u-id-key=980786711&u-key-ver=1&aid=19kJy545FwEVqg22z7oQugRpmufx44b5xXnbw889oDs%3D&d-device-screen-size=480*800&d-localization=en-US&d-orientation=1&d-devicename=XDeviceEmulator&u-appver=1.0.0.0&u-appdnm=Match1&u-appbid=fcc4c048-4686-42bc-a40c-b7fe8da70b40&d-nettype=wifi&mk-siteid=26e654aa92d146fbac8f1640acf31030&mk-version=pr-SWPH-CTATE-20140116&mk-rel-version=pr-SWPH-CTATE-20140116&format=xhtml&mk-ads=1&h-user-agent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(compatible%3B%20MSIE%2010.0%3B%20Windows%20Phone%208.0%3B%20Trident%2F6.0%3B%20IEMobile%2F10.0%3B%20ARM%3B%20Touch%3B%20Microsoft%3B%20Virtual)&mk-ad-slot=11&u-rt=1]
>   2014-07-06 00:53:51,240 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG
>   ServerURL:http://i.w.inmobi.com:80/showad.asm 2014-07-06 00:53:51,256
>   InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG   NetworkManager.GetAd--> Request Message:
>   u-id-map=TLqn3wQW8B%2BDNjTXtCX3SXsOxxaoFICPINnBAvgwJMlDM12JpBKkXE%2FmTDdFaEFYDvq0p0sfhm8VkXXBKF7JYGdUg5Os7sHAIy%2BzTbE0DAC4oBtTLoEGaGNaCUbvrExJRBMtYY5T9Nmg6%2BUwT9I2PieNvMOfuQoj4wNGQZ%2FLSBc%3D&u-id-key=980786711&u-key-ver=1&aid=19kJy545FwEVqg22z7oQugRpmufx44b5xXnbw889oDs%3D&d-device-screen-size=480*800&d-localization=en-US&d-orientation=1&d-devicename=XDeviceEmulator&u-appver=1.0.0.0&u-appdnm=Match1&u-appbid=fcc4c048-4686-42bc-a40c-b7fe8da70b40&d-nettype=wifi&mk-siteid=26e654aa92d146fbac8f1640acf31030&mk-version=pr-SWPH-CTATE-20140116&mk-rel-version=pr-SWPH-CTATE-20140116&format=xhtml&mk-ads=1&h-user-agent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(compatible%3B%20MSIE%2010.0%3B%20Windows%20Phone%208.0%3B%20Trident%2F6.0%3B%20IEMobile%2F10.0%3B%20ARM%3B%20Touch%3B%20Microsoft%3B%20Virtual)&mk-ad-slot=11&u-rt=1
>   2014-07-06 00:53:51,271 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG Sent Ad Request
>   2014-07-06 00:53:51,916 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG AdResponse
>   [<,bp,bp,h.bodyk,S.f(b))};f[a+A]=function(a){T(c,a)};f[a+K]=function(){U(c)};f[a+N]=function(a,b){V(c,a,b)}}f.inmobi.Bolt=S;
>   S.f=function(a){if(typeof a.click==E)a.click.call(a);else
>   if(a.fireEvent)a.fireEvent(L);else if(a.dispatchEvent){var
>   c=h.createEvent(w);c.initEvent(z,!1,!0);a.dispatchEvent(c)}};S.b=function(a){return
>   a.replace(/\$TS/g,q+(new Date).getTime())};function W(a,c){var
>   d=h.getElementById(a.a+B),b=hn;bp;bp;bp;bp;dk}
>   function T(a,c){var d=f[a.a+H];d&&d();for(var
>   d=a.c.length,b=0;bn;bp;bp;bp;ck;var
>   g=b.contentWindow;g&&g.document.write(d)}catch(m){}} function
>   V(a,c,d){function b(c,d,g){if(!(0>=g)){var
>   m=h.getElementById(a.a+B),l=hn;lp;lp;lp;void
>   0!=l.addEventListener&&l.addEventListener(C,function(){f.setTimeout(function(){3E5k}}var
>   g=a.e,g=g+(v+c);if(d)for(var m in
>   d)g+=r+e(m)+u+e(d[m]);b(g,1E3,5);18==c&&U(a);8==c&&T(a,null)};})();
>   new
>   window.inmobi.Bolt({"lp":"http://diagnostics-lp.inmobi.com","lps":"https://prclick.inmobi.com/redir/http://diagnostics-lp.inmobi.com","ct":["http://c.w.inmobi.com/c.asm/C/t/dtuccbshdf/10nu/c/b/a0/u/0/0/0/eyJVSUQiOiIxOWtKeTU0NUZ3RVZxZzIyejdvUXVnUnBtdWNcdTAwM2QiLCJPMSI6IjE5a0p5NTQ1RndFVnFnMjJ6N29RdWdScG11Y1x1MDAzZCIsIklYIjoiZGM3NjUyN2NiN2E0YTlkMTU0NDJiZjcxMjc4MTE5NTYifQ~~/0fbe63f2-0147-1000-dcc0-3eb71fff0060/w204/0/-1/1/1/x/2625358/NW/2t/0/sdk/2.0.4/dir/ZmNjNGMwNDgtNDY4Ni00MmJjLWE0MGMtYjdmZThkYTcwYjQw/6/d2ed78?at\u003d1\u0026am\u003d0"],"bcu":"http://et.w.inmobi.com/c.asm/C/t/dtuccbshdf/10nu/c/b/a0/u/0/0/0/eyJVSUQiOiIxOWtKeTU0NUZ3RVZxZzIyejdvUXVnUnBtdWNcdTAwM2QiLCJPMSI6IjE5a0p5NTQ1RndFVnFnMjJ6N29RdWdScG11Y1x1MDAzZCIsIklYIjoiZGM3NjUyN2NiN2E0YTlkMTU0NDJiZjcxMjc4MTE5NTYifQ~~/0fbe63f2-0147-1000-dcc0-3eb71fff0060/w204/0/-1/0/1/x/2625358/NW/2t/0/sdk/2.0.4/dir/ZmNjNGMwNDgtNDY4Ni00MmJjLWE0MGMtYjdmZThkYTcwYjQw/6/2bdbd8c1","ws":true,"ns":"im_3466_"});
>   (function() {var
>   b=window,c='handleClick',d='handleTouchEnd',f='handleTouchStart';b.inmobi=b.inmobi||{};var
>   g=b.inmobi;function h(a,e){return function(l){e.call(a,l)}}function
>   k(a,e){this.b=e;this.a=this.c=!1;b[a+c]=h(this,this.click);b[a+f]=h(this,this.start);b[a+d]=h(this,this.end)}k.prototype.click=function(){this.c||this.b()};k.prototype.start=function(a){this.a=this.c=!0;a&&a.preventDefault()};k.prototype.end=function(){this.a&&(this.a=!1,this.b())};g.OldTap=k;})();
>   new window.inmobi.OldTap("im_3466_", function() {
>   window'im_3466_openLandingPage';
>   window'im_3466_clickCallback'; }); </script>   </div> body{margin:0}</style>
>    im_3466_recordEvent(18);
>   </script>]]></Ad></Ads></AdResponse> ] 2014-07-06 00:53:52,616 InMobi
>   SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG Current_SizeChanged Screen Size:
>   [{"height":800,"width":480}] Mraid Rotation Angle:[0]  2014-07-06
>   00:53:52,679 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG Raising screen position change
>   event 2014-07-06 00:53:52,712 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG Screen position
>   {"height":90,"width":728,"x":-2,"y":702} 2014-07-06 00:53:52,730
>   InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG Ad container recieved script
>   notificationlog|Bridge::fireOrientationChangeEvent. Orientation:0
>   2014-07-06 00:53:52,748 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG
>   Bridge::fireOrientationChangeEvent. Orientation:0 2014-07-06
>   00:53:52,777 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG Ad container recieved script
>   notificationlog|Bridge:: fireStateChangeEvent Called. State:default
>   2014-07-06 00:53:52,793 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG Bridge::
>   fireStateChangeEvent Called. State:default 2014-07-06 00:53:52,808
>   InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG Ad container recieved script
>   notificationlog|Bridge:: fireViewableChangeEvent called.
>   IsViewable:true 2014-07-06 00:53:52,824 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG
>   Bridge:: fireViewableChangeEvent called. IsViewable:true 2014-07-06
>   00:53:52,840 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG Ad container recieved script
>   notificationlog|Bridge::firePlacementChangeEvent called.
>   Placement:inline 2014-07-06 00:53:52,855 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG
>   Bridge::firePlacementChangeEvent called. Placement:inline 2014-07-06
>   00:53:52,876 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG Ad container recieved script
>   notificationlog|Bridge:: fireReadyEvent called 2014-07-06 00:53:52,886
>   InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG Bridge:: fireReadyEvent called 2014-07-06
>   00:53:52,902 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG IMAdView::IMAdContainer_AdRendered
>   FirstIMAdContainer Ad request loaded. 2014-07-06 00:54:03,558 InMobi
>   SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG UserAgent: [Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0;
>   Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; Microsoft;
>   Virtual)] Publisher device Id is: 19kJy545FwEVqg22z7oQugRpmuc=
>   2014-07-06 00:54:03,743 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG Sending Ad Request
>   [u-id-map=jYb2yI3iG6gR%2F6sDYMWWDj6ifQlEv9KM6YVl74JsNcdzL9ZzNAjrnRKRiFIsH0Y0IlNKIKe8GC2MAUph3htz2Tftljoarpyr70VbFFgD4bGc3INs3GPzSPKGFrqoAkRfdTO1BQ3tIyvi%2Ba%2BlZ5xiZ45K6USS4UzIxpoz1S%2Fep8I%3D&u-id-key=1540821693&u-key-ver=1&aid=19kJy545FwEVqg22z7oQugRpmufx44b5xXnbw889oDs%3D&d-device-screen-size=480*800&d-localization=en-US&d-orientation=1&d-devicename=XDeviceEmulator&u-appver=1.0.0.0&u-appdnm=Match1&u-appbid=fcc4c048-4686-42bc-a40c-b7fe8da70b40&d-nettype=wifi&mk-siteid=fcc4c048-4686-42bc-a40c-b7fe8da70b40&mk-version=pr-SWPH-CTATE-20140116&mk-rel-version=pr-SWPH-CTATE-20140116&format=xhtml&mk-ads=1&h-user-agent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(compatible%3B%20MSIE%2010.0%3B%20Windows%20Phone%208.0%3B%20Trident%2F6.0%3B%20IEMobile%2F10.0%3B%20ARM%3B%20Touch%3B%20Microsoft%3B%20Virtual)&mk-ad-slot=25&u-rt=1]
>   2014-07-06 00:54:03,782 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG
>   ServerURL:http://i.w.inmobi.com:80/showad.asm 2014-07-06 00:54:03,799
>   InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG   NetworkManager.GetAd--> Request Message:
>   u-id-map=jYb2yI3iG6gR%2F6sDYMWWDj6ifQlEv9KM6YVl74JsNcdzL9ZzNAjrnRKRiFIsH0Y0IlNKIKe8GC2MAUph3htz2Tftljoarpyr70VbFFgD4bGc3INs3GPzSPKGFrqoAkRfdTO1BQ3tIyvi%2Ba%2BlZ5xiZ45K6USS4UzIxpoz1S%2Fep8I%3D&u-id-key=1540821693&u-key-ver=1&aid=19kJy545FwEVqg22z7oQugRpmufx44b5xXnbw889oDs%3D&d-device-screen-size=480*800&d-localization=en-US&d-orientation=1&d-devicename=XDeviceEmulator&u-appver=1.0.0.0&u-appdnm=Match1&u-appbid=fcc4c048-4686-42bc-a40c-b7fe8da70b40&d-nettype=wifi&mk-siteid=fcc4c048-4686-42bc-a40c-b7fe8da70b40&mk-version=pr-SWPH-CTATE-20140116&mk-rel-version=pr-SWPH-CTATE-20140116&format=xhtml&mk-ads=1&h-user-agent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(compatible%3B%20MSIE%2010.0%3B%20Windows%20Phone%208.0%3B%20Trident%2F6.0%3B%20IEMobile%2F10.0%3B%20ARM%3B%20Touch%3B%20Microsoft%3B%20Virtual)&mk-ad-slot=25&u-rt=1
>   2014-07-06 00:54:03,814 InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG Sent Ad Request

Comment: Hey! I"m from the InMobi team. Here is the integration guide: https://www.inmobi.com/support/integration/23925038/22188957/windows-phone-8-sdk-integration-guide/

Did you try the test mode? You can use that when you don't need to display live ads. Will be very helpful if you can post some logs as well.

Comment: Yaa Sir i'm tryng test mode only.

Comment: Can you post some logs please?

Answer (score 0):

This sort of exception can happen if the following capability is not added to the manifest.xml

```
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING"/>
```

Also, from the logs I can see

> InMobi SDK 2.0.4 DEBUG IMAdView::IMAdContainer_AdRendered
>   SecondIMAdContainer Ad request loaded

Which means you have received your ad request and that you should display it.